# Soundex to match common SMS or IM short forms

Tags: pattern-matching, matching, string-matching, codec, soundex

I was doing bit of experimentation the Apache commons soundex. And, I found it works quite well for strings. I was looking for an API or way by which I can match words or strings in sms or usual IM formats formats which are like soundex. The following are some examples,

- "4" to match with "four" or "for"
- "@" to match with "at"
- so on and so forth...

  Is there an API existing to do this already? or a way to tweak the existing Soundex API to do this? Appreciate your time and help.

Thanks,
Abi